# Creating heat map of video content for specific pixels in each frame as data input

Tags: matlab, video, data-visualization

I am trying to make heatmaps for video content. For each frame in the video, I have data of specific pixels that are the focus points, and I would like to reproduce the video in a heatmap form according to the pixel coordinates(30 per frame) I have for each frame. Would that be possible to produce in Matlab, even if its done only for some specific frames, rather than the entire video? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of the pixels, you can mark them in a 2D binary matrix for each frame.  Then add all the matrices, and plot the result using the imagesc command.  Here's an example with random pixel locations.

```
X = zeros(10,10,50); % Create 50 empty frames

for i = 1:50 % Loop through each frame
    % Generate 30 random pixel locations
    pixel_x = randi(10,[30,1]);
    pixel_y = randi(10,[30,1]);
    % Mark pixel locations in frame with 1's
    for j = 1:30
        X(pixel_y(j),pixel_x(j),i) = 1;
    end
end

% Sum frames
X_sum = sum(X,3)

% Plot heatmap
figure
imagesc(X_sum)
colormap hot
colorbar
```

[image: Heatmap]